# Inviting for wedding reception correct sentence formation

Tags: sentence

I am preparing my wedding invitation. Am currently using "The celebration continues with a" , but there is two reception ceremony, one before the wedding and one after. So I got two images implying two venues.

My Question is, is it correct to use "The celebration Continues with a " or "Come join us for the reception of". Had the latter earlier but it didn't sound grammatically correct to me. Please help me forming the sentence.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your current wording. However, if you anticipate any confusion, you could provide a brief schedule of events on either a separate notecard or the main invitation.

However, I'd recommend changing to:

**Following the ceremony, please join us at ...**

People understand they're going from a ceremony to a party; I don't think you need to spell that part out.